# My request URL is not receiving any events for the Slack Events API. What am I missing?

Tags: slack-api, slack

I want to subscribe to Slack Events API for any message posted in a slack channel. These are the following steps I took as given in Slack Event API [documentations](https://api.slack.com/events-api).

1. I created a slack app with following permission scopes :

   - channels:history, groups:history, im:history, mpim:history
2. In Event Subscriptions, I enabled events, verified Request URL ( "https://api.example.com/slack/event/push") successfully, and subscribed to the following Team Events :

   - channel_history_changed, group_history_changed, message.channels, message.groups, message.im, message.mpim
3. I made the user go through oauth authorization to install the app. The url is shown below with scope and redirect uri. (PHP Code)

   $url = "https://slack.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=" . SLACK_CLIENT_ID .
           "&scope=users.profile:read,users:read,groups:history,channels:history,im:history,mpim:history" .
           "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode('https://api.example.com/slack/oauth/callback') .
           "&state=XXXXXXXXX";
4. I receive a code from slack which I exchange for access token.

   Access Token: xoxp-XXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
   Scope: identify,channels:history,groups:history,im:history,mpim:history,users:read,users.profile:read
   Team Id: XXXXXXXX

I checked the apps and integration of the team to see if the app was installed and yes it is in the list of Apps.

Now as per my understanding when any message is posted in any channel of the team, a POST request should be made to my verified URL ( "https://api.example.com/slack/event/push"). But I don't get any POST request there.

I thought maybe the URL is broken but I tested it with a counter and every time the URL is hit it increments the counter. So the URL is fine.

Is there a step I missed somewhere? I don't know what to try next.

Comment: Your approach looks ok. One thing I would try is to make sure your PHP script really receives the POST requests. Activate full logging on your script and you use the [hurl.it](https://www.hurl.it/) tool to send a POST request to it. I would also try from a public channel first.

Comment: I thought that could be a reason and tested my endpoint thoroughly. My POST endpoint does nothing but increment a counter in redis cache for now. I am watching if the counter is incremented. When I hit the endpoint from POSTMAN or browser it increments fine, which means the endpoint is not faulty. I event tested with hurl.it and there's no problem.
I read in one of the docs if the endpoint returns too many errors then its deactivated for a while. I thought that could be a reason since it was returning error when I first set it up. But its been a day now and still I don't see any post requests

Comment: Does the urlencode transform your redirects url right ? And does `redirect_uri - must match the originally submitted URI (if one was sent)`?

Comment: @DomeTune Yes it does transform correctly and the value of redirect_uri is same. If it did not transform correctly or my redirect_uri was different, i'm guessing my Oauth process would fail. But the oauth process has no problem and I get a valid access_token. Also, the app gets added to the Slack Team as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I contacted Slack support and they were very helpful. The logs at slack showed that Slack was actually sending POST requests to my Request url. So my setup worked fine. But my API framework was failing to parse the request body and hence sending internal server error (500) to Slack. We figured this out by using [requestb.in](http://requestb.in/).

All I had to do was change the way I parsed request body.

Comment: I thought I would get a quicker response here. I was not aware that slack support was so good. They got back to me within an hour.

Comment: No, I am just telling that you could do that before adding a bounty.

Answer (score 0):

***Many years later***

To elaborate on the answer above... The Slack Events API will send a post request to your endpoint with a challenge to verify your url, but they don't explicitly tell you that it's:

`Content-Type: application/json`

so if you are assuming it's `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and you are attempting to retrieve the individual paramaters with the format `key1=value1&key2=value2&key3=value3`, it will appear that there are none, because it's not parsing the json in the body of the request.

Answer (score -2):

Having the channel be public is VERY important!

Comment: Please explain what you mean, also give code examples. Your answer as it is now is not very helpful put yourself in the shoes of the person asking the question.

Comment: @katalinablues Don't know what I was looking for, but this comment helped me. Thanks